# Object Tracking in non static environment

Tags: matlab, opencv, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I am working on a drone based video surveillance project. I am required to implement object tracking in the same. I have tried conventional approaches but these seem to fail due to non static environment.

[This is an example](http://in.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/detecting-cars-using-gaussian-mixture-models.html)  of what i would want to achieve. But this uses background subtraction which is impossible to achieve with a non static camera.

I have also tried feature based tracking using [SURF features](http://in.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/object-detection-in-a-cluttered-scene-using-point-feature-matching.html?refresh=true), but it fails for smaller objects and is prone to false positives.

What would be the best way to achieve the objective in this scenario ?.

Edit : An object can be anything within a  defined region of interest. The object will usually be a person or a vehicle. The idea is that the user will make a bounding box which will define the region of interest. The drone now has to start tracking whatever is within this region of interest.

Comment: How are you defining an "object"? This may seem like a simple question but try and think about the specific things you want to track. E.G. Do you want to track a tank (If so do you want it to be determined if the tank is friend/foe?) Do you want to track people? Do you want to track stray dogs? If you are flying over an ocean, do you want to track waves? Please give more specific information if you want a relevant answer.

Comment: Could you first explain what an object is? The first algorithm extracts all moving objects, the second recognizes previously learned objects. I am not sure what you really need.

Comment: @ChrisBritt i have edited the question. Thanks for seeking clarification.

Comment: @HARJATINSINGH If you are having the user define a region of interest, I would explore modifying/using the SURF feature detectors or something like HAAR Cascades. Even if the current algorithm doesn't work properly, you can always use that as a starting point for a new algorithm. How "small" is "small that doesn't work properly", and are you able to adjust the images resolution? Also, play around with how many features it is detecting, and how much they can vary from time to time.

Comment: @ChrisBritt i think that the problem with SURF features is that in case of surveillance feed it is often that the object of interest merges with the background thus the features such as edges are not very apparent. But i will give HAAR cascade a shot.

Comment: @HARJATINSINGH If the problem is that you can't tell the object from the background have you considered writing a pre-processing system that will increase contrast, adjust lighting, etc?

Comment: Thanks @ChrisBritt. Will try it out

Comment: I think this question is too broad. I think you would be far better of by re-writing the question so that it includes a single scenario e.g. humans and include sample images together with the expected output. Please see [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You could add a video as an animated gif.

Comment: @ChrisBritt  also tried camshift here. But in practice it does not do very well. Can you provide an explanation for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tracking local features (like SURF) won't work in your case. Training a classifier (like Boosting with HAAR features) won't work either. Let me explain why.

Your object to track will be contained in a bounding box. Inside this bounding box there could be any object, not a *person*, a *car*, or something else that you used to train you classifier.

Also, near the object, in the bounding box there will be also background noise that will change as soon as your target object moves, even if the appearance of the object doesn't change.
Moreover the appearance of you object changes (e.g. a person turns, or drop the jacket, a vehicle get a reflection of the sun, etc...), or the object gets (partially or totally) occluded for a while. So tracking local features is very likely to lose the tracked object very soon.

So the **first problem** is that you must deal with potentially a lot of different objects, possibly unknown a priori, to track and you cannot train a classifier for each one of these.

The **second problem** is that you must follow an object whose appearance may change, so you need to update your model.

The **third problem** is that you need some logic that tells you that you lost the tracked object, and you need to detect it again in the scene.

---

So what to do? Well, you need a good *long term tracker*.

One of the best (to my knowledge) is Tracking-Learning-Detection (TLD) by [Kalal et. al.](http://kahlan.eps.surrey.ac.uk/featurespace/tld/Publications/2011_tpami). You can see on the dedicated [page](http://kahlan.eps.surrey.ac.uk/featurespace/tld/) a lot of example videos, and you can see that it works pretty good with moving cameras, objects that change appearance, etc...

Luckily for us, OpenCV 3.0.0 has an implementation for [TLD](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/tracking/doc/tracker_algorithms.html#trackertld), and you can find a sample code [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/52872/how-to-perform-tld-tracking-on-roi-bounding-box-using-opencv-c-builtin-methods/?answer=52882#post-id-52882) (there is also a Matlab + C implementation in the aforementioned site).

The main drawback is that this method could be slow. You can test if it's an issue for you. If so, you can downsample the video stream, upgrade your hardware, or switch to a faster tracking method, but this depends on you requirements and needs.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. Will try TLD out right away.

Comment: I also tried camshift here. But in practice it does not do very well. Can you provide an explanation for this ?

Comment: Not an expert, but probably it's because the features (model) you're tracking is not so robust or discriminating.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to try is frame differencing instead of background subtraction. Subtract the previous frame from the current frame, threshold the difference image to make it binary, and then use some morphology to clean up the noise. With this approach you typically only get the edges of the objects, but often that is enough for tracking.

You can also try to augment this approach using `vision.PointTracker`, which implements the KLT (Kanad-Lucas-Tomasi) point tracking algorithm.

Alternatively, you can try using dense optical flow.  See [opticalFlowLK](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/opticalflowlk-class.html), [opticalFlowHS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/opticalflowhs-class.html), and [opticalFlowLKDoG](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/opticalflowlkdog-class.html).

Comment: Can you explain frame differencing in a little more detail ?  I have already tried point tracker with Eigen Features. It didn't seem to work very well.